# Nginx proxy_pass to Angular app inside a docker container

Tags: angular, docker, nginx

I have a docker container which is running nginx and hosting an Angular app.

If I access the app directly via the server's IP and container port (2000), it loads normally.

However, I want to setup a routing rule for the app on an existing nginx running on the server, outside the container.

I have configured the rule as follows:

```
location /dashboard {
    rewrite /dashboard/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:2000/;
}
```

It seems to be routed correctly, because I see the app title in the browser, but I get 404 errors for all compiled scripts, which are referenced inside index.html.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please clarify your configuration. Do you have one server which is running two instances of Nginx, one within the context of a Docker container and other which runs as standalone. And your goal is to create a redirection from the standalone Nginx to access an Angular App within the Docker container. Is that correct?

Comment: That's correct. The server itself is running its own nginx, because it serves as a reverse proxy for multiple other apps as well. The second nginx is run inside a Docker container and its only purpose is to host the compiled Angular app within that container. The first nginx instance has a rule (as described in my initial post) to redirect to the nginx within the container.